# Objective-C object typedef yields strange @encode and breaks KVC

Tags: objective-c, typedef

Consider the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

typedef NSString* MyStringRef;
typedef NSString MyString;

@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyStringRef stringA;
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyString *stringB;
@end

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize stringA = _stringA;
@synthesize stringB = _stringB;
@end

int main() {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList([ClassA class], &count);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Ivar thisIvar = ivars[i];
        NSLog(@"thisIvar = %s, %s", ivar_getName(thisIvar), ivar_getTypeEncoding(thisIvar));
    }

    ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Out: %@", [a valueForKey:@"stringA"]);
    NSLog(@"Out: %@", [a valueForKey:@"stringB"]);
}
```

This is the output:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix

$ clang -o typedef -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation typedef.m && ./typedef
2012-06-06 20:14:15.881 typedef[37282:707] thisIvar = _stringA, @"NSString"
2012-06-06 20:14:15.884 typedef[37282:707] thisIvar = _stringB, ^{NSString=#}
2012-06-06 20:14:15.885 typedef[37282:707] Out: (null)
2012-06-06 20:14:15.888 typedef[37282:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ClassA 0x7fabe0501480> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key stringB.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff835fef56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff878e5d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff836891b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff83e77703 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 240
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff83dae38e _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 108
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff83dae315 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 392
    6   typedef                             0x000000010e84bc6d main + 317
    7   typedef                             0x000000010e84b9c4 start + 52
)
```

The question I have here is what is it about Objective-C that causes the `typedef NSString MyString` to effectively create a struct that contains one variable of type `Class` and then uses that where I use `MyString`. e.g. the struct looks like this (after consulting [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)):

```
struct NSString {
    Class a;
};
```

It sort of makes sense but causes the `valueForKey:` to fail, presumably because it's a struct now, so it can't return that in the same way as objects. Or more precisely, it falls into the "throw exception" part of the search order [described in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-138234-BAJCAJGJ).

I'd just like to understand what it is about the language that causes this to happen and why it can't treat my 2 typedefs in the same way.

Comment: Although you synthesize the properties, you don't seem to have an actual ivar backing them.

Comment: Recent versions of the compiler create ivars for synthesized properties automatically.

Comment: In general, @encode strings aren't terribly useful.  They quickly become overly complex when dealing with C++ types, for example.

Comment: @bbum - Sure, but it's not really the `@encode` I care about here. It's that it breaks KVC as I show.

Comment: Any further ideas anyone? @bbum ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer to this at WWDC 2012. It turns out that this behaviour is expected as is for binary compatibility with GCC.

Seems odd to me that they'd effectively introduce what I would consider a bug to be binary compatible with old GCCs. I hope that this sort of thing will eventually be phased out in favour of a correct compiler.

Comment: I think I am seeing this with clang 4.2, FWIW. Consistent with it being intended misbehavior.

Comment: Indeed. That's what Apple said.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this, but only with gcc.  With clang, I get:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 1.7 (tags/Apple/clang-77) (based on LLVM 2.9svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Thread model: posix
$ ./a.out
2012-06-06 15:16:37.947 a.out[61063:903] thisIvar = _stringA, @"NSString"
2012-06-06 15:16:37.949 a.out[61063:903] thisIvar = _stringB, @"NSString"
2012-06-06 15:16:37.949 a.out[61063:903] Out: (null)
2012-06-06 15:16:37.950 a.out[61063:903] Out: (null)
```

So, it seems the clang developers agree with you about how it should work.

(I also tried Apple clang version 3.0. Same good result.)

Comment: Interesting, since I am using clang as well. Do you have ARC enabled in that?

Comment: Added my clang version and command line I used for building to my question.

Comment: Not using ARC. `clang -std=gnu99 foo.m -framework Foundation` I needed gnu99 because of the declaration of `i` within the `for` loop.

Comment: Interesting. No ARC for me causes the same problem. Note that my example is leaky without ARC (and it's leaky anyway due to not `free()`-ing the ivar list) but that is irrelevant really for this anyway.